# File upload blocking with bigger files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

### Intro

What I'm trying to achieve is a simple file upload with a progress indication with redux-saga and react). I'm having problems getting this indication because the file upload seems the be blocking - which it shouldn't be.

### Expected behaviour

before the file upload starts a re render is triggered and the spinner is shown and the window is not blocked.

### Current behaviour

What I have at the moment is a component with a table that show a file per row. A optimistic row gets added with a spinner as the content when the users uploads a file. As soon as the file is uploaded the optimistic row will be replaced by a real row with the file's name etc. When I'm uploading a file around 50MB the window gets blocked and shortly before the file is uploaded (around 0.5s before) the spinner appears and then the file is already uploaded and the spinner disappears again.

---

#### side notes

- If you replace the file upload with `new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5000))` it all works fine => it seems like there is a problem with the xhr / fetch.
- I've implemented the same using XHR, promises and an onProgress callback to make sure the problem is not fetch.
  the implementation looks very close to: https://gist.github.com/robinfehr/2f4018259bf026a468cc31100fed5c9f
  Also with this implementation I've experienced the same issue - blocking until almost the end of the upload.
- If I put log statements into the render function of the component to see if it's getting re rendered before the file is uploaded, I see (as soon as the block stops and the file is uploaded) that the log statements in the render function are actually correctly triggered with a timestamp before the file upload was done.
- In this implementation I'm using the same reducer: optimistic event as well as the real event that reverts the optimistic event, they go trough the same reducer (named fileReducer here).
- ***using a second reducer and concatination instead of the optimistic revert logic helps to displaying the spinner earlier but does not help with the blocking. It therefore seems like the middleware also gets blocked by the blocking call.***

---

### saga: (postData uses fetch)

```
function* createDocument(partnerId, { payload, meta }) {
  const siteId = getSiteIdFromRoute();
  const {
    mediaGroupId,
    customArticleId,
    logicalComponentId,
    type,
    name,
    documentSrc,
    meta: metaFromFrontEnd
  } = payload;

  const commonEventId = uuid();
  const hans = {
    optimistic: true
  };
  const payloadBasic = {
    id: commonEventId,
    version: 0,
    aggregate: {
      id: uuid(),
      name: 'document'
    },
    context: {
      name: 'contentManagement'
    },
    payload: {
      name,
      type,
      links: {
        partnerId,
        siteId,
        logicalComponentId,
        customArticleId,
        mediaGroupId
      }
    }
  };

  // creates the optimistic (fake) row with a spinner in the file list component - action marked as optimistic which will be reverted.
  yield put(actions.denormalizeEvent({
    ...payloadBasic,
    name: 'documentCreated',
    optimistic: true,
    payload: {
      ...payloadBasic.payload,
      uploading: true
    }
  }));
  yield fork(executeDocumentUpload, type, siteId, partnerId, documentSrc, payloadBasic);
}

function* executeDocumentUpload(type, siteId, partnerId, documentSrc, payloadBasic) {
  const req = yield call(uploadDocument, type, siteId, partnerId, documentSrc);
  const body = yield req.json();
  const { meta: metaFromFileUpload, id } = body.response;
  // removes the optimistic (fake) row from the file list component and and adds the real row with more file information (optimistic event gets reverted in middleware)
  yield put(actions.sendCommandSuccess({
    ...payloadBasic,
    name: 'createDocument',
    payload: {
      ...payloadBasic.payload,
      meta: metaFromFileUpload
    }
  }));
}

function uploadDocument(type, siteId, partnerId, documentSrc) {
  let url;
  if (type === 'site' || type === 'mediaGroup' || type ===     'logicalComponent') {
    url = `/file/site/${siteId}/document`;
  } else if (type === 'customArticle') {
    url = `/file/partner/${partnerId}/document`;
  }
  return postData(url, documentSrc);
}
```

Comment: The expected behavior occurs with a smaller file?

Comment: @SH yes, but of course it's less noticeable because the file is uploaded much faster.

Comment: What is actions.denormalizeEvent & actions.sendCommandSuccess?

Comment: @SH its a CQRS environment - sendCommandSuccess action will send a command to the domain - the event coming back from the domain will result in a denormalizeEvent action. the denormalizeEvent action therefore is the action triggered to modify the redux state - it's payload determines which reducer handles the action (there is a wrapper). - Ill add comments to the questions - thanks.

Comment: It is hard to say exactly, but it seems that `actions.denormalizeEvent` depends on a later event? (actions.sendCommandSuccess?)

Comment: @SH- i've added comments to the code - the first denormalizeEvent is a optimistic one one which triggers the first rerender and adds an optimistic row, the second indirectly will also trigger a denormalizeEvent which has no more optimistic flag and will revert the first added event from the history and therefore revert the optimistic row and add a real one with more information of the file instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137377/discussion-between-sh-and-robin-f).

Comment: I would try putting a short delay in `createDocument` between putting the `denormalizeEvent` action and forking to `executeDocumentUpload`.

Comment: @PatrickHund just tried, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did send the file as a base64 encode string and set up the request with the wrong content-type.

`'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'`

putting the file into a FormData object and send the request without the mentioned content-type lead to a non-blocking request.